# Calling timeout inside an object, function get called immediately

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

I made a jsfiddle for you:

http://jsfiddle.net/fyJP2/

This is the code:

```
var chat = {

    init: function(){
        setTimeout( comet , 10);
    }
};

function comet()
{
    alert('called');
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  chat.init();
});
```

As you can see comet() is called immediately ignoring completely the delay of 10 seconds, why? I am passing comet and not comet() as setTimeout requires, but the function is still executed.
I originally thought it was a scope issue so I moved comet to its own function, but doing this: http://jsfiddle.net/fyJP2/1/ the result is the same.

Can someone explain me why?

Comment: It is 10 MILLIseconds, see the manual :-)

Comment: Thanks guys, I now feel stupid.

Answer (score 2):

As has been pointed out the second argument passed to `window.setTimeout` is in milliseconds.
Therefore your code should be:

```
init: function(){
    setTimeout( comet , 10000);
}
```

Presuming you meant ten seconds, that is.

Read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout

Comment: I was blind, now I see. Will be accepting in 7 minutes. Was going crazy over this little thing.

Comment: No probs. Easy mistake to make :)